# How to get to an MvxViewController from a regular UiViewController? Is it possible?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am new to MvvmCross, but all the samples I find seems to rely on

```
    var start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
    start.Start();
```

To instantiate all the MvxViewControllers.

But my app starts from a non-MvxViewController, and I don't want to turn my start up viewcontroller into an MvxViewController.

I would like to instantiate a MvxViewController and push it to my navigation stack, something like this:

```
    var vc = Mvx.Resolve<SomeMvxViewController>();
    NavigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);
```

Is that possible?

Comment: What you need to do is launch your app normally and in AppDelegate, set the RootViewController of your app to a normal (non-mvx) UIViewController. Then in that UIViewContoller, do you initialization for MvvmCross - like creating the Setup objet and registering the presenter.

Comment: What if I have a set of ViewControllers that I want to keep that are non-mvx? 
I have an existing project with a bunch of non-mvx viewcontrollers that I don't want to convert, and I just want to push an MVX viewcontroller on top of my existing navigation stack.

Comment: One way would be a custom presenter instead of the one MvvmCross provides out of the box to expose a set of navigation APIs that can intelligently decided if the requested ViewController is an MvxViewController or not and do the appropriate navigation.